# Mathematica - How to set default stylesheet

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, default, stylesheet

I want to change my default stylesheet to StandardReport, but all I find when I google this problem is how to set a custom stylesheet as default stylesheet. Can someone please tell me how I set a non-custom stylesheet as default.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, DefaultStyleDefinitions->"Untitled.nb"]
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out (for Windows):

1) Select the stylesheet you want to use as default (under "Format -> Stylesheet") (in my case I choose StandardReport).

2) Press "Format -> Edit Stylesheet". You should now see a line that says "Inheriting base definitions from stylesheet "Report"" ("Report" is different depending on which stylesheet you want to have as default).

3) Save the file as whatever name that pleases you, e.g. I used "Untitled.nb".

4) Place this file under "...\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\StyleSheets".

5) In Mathematica, press "Format -> Option Inspector".

6) Choose "Show option values -> Global Preferences".

7) Search for "DefaultStyleDefinitions" and choose your file (in my case the "Untitled.nb" file).

You've now changed the default stylesheet for Mathematica. :)